# How to retrieve and save Asterisk phonebook entries via ARI?

Tags: asterisk, api, pbx, freepbx

How can I retrieve/update/add Asterisk phonebook entries via ARI? I'm looking at ARI documentation https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+ARI, but I don't find anything about the phonebook...

The phonebook I'm talking about is the one I find in FreePBX Administration > Admin > Asterisk Phonebook.

I also tried to look for the phonebook entries in the MySQL database, but don't see them there either...

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk itself is PBX and not store nor manage phonebooks or phonebooks entries. It have no API for that.

If you have FreePBX framework(Elastic < 5.0, Trixbox), it store phonebook in astdb. So it is accessable via AMI by checking DB/DB_GET functions. ARI may have similar function, check ARI doc.

For any other framework you should refer to framework documentation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. We do use FreePBX (14.0.2.10). So the question is if ARI can access that astdb...

Comment: Oh, is `astdb` just an SQLite database? The one located at `/var/lib/asterisk/astdb.sqlite3`?

Comment: Depend of version AND compilation options. For 1.4  it is just text file.